NoSuchMethodError attempting to connect to Azure Service Bus Queue using Spring Boot
I am developing a Spring Boot application that will consume from an Azure Service Bus queue. I have followed the instructions found in use-the-spring-cloud-azure-service-bus-starter but when I attempt to start the application I see the following in the below log.
I have set the following properties in my application.properties file:
spring.cloud.azure.servicebus.namespace
spring.cloud.azure.servicebus.entity-name
spring.cloud.azure.servicebus.entity-type

I am using Java 17, the most current versions of Spring Boot and Azure dependencies and I have performed:
az login 

successfully in my local environment.
According the the document referenced above this is all I should need to do. Anyone have any thoughts on what I might be missing or what I am doing incorrectly?
2024-04-01T12:34:38.528-04:00  INFO 34956 --- [ctor-executor-1] c.a.i.ChainedTokenCredential             : Azure Identity => Attempted credential EnvironmentCredential is unavailable.
2024-04-01T12:34:38.529-04:00  INFO 34956 --- [ctor-executor-1] c.a.i.ChainedTokenCredential             : Azure Identity => Attempted credential WorkloadIdentityCredential is unavailable.
2024-04-01T12:34:38.543-04:00  WARN 34956 --- [ctor-executor-1] r.c.Exceptions                           : throwIfFatal detected a jvm fatal exception, which is thrown and logged below:

java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: 'com.microsoft.aad.msal4j.AbstractClientApplicationBase$Builder com.microsoft.aad.msal4j.ConfidentialClientApplication$Builder.logPii(boolean)'
        at com.azure.identity.implementation.IdentityClientBase.getManagedIdentityConfidentialClient(IdentityClientBase.java:393) ~[azure-identity-1.11.2.jar:1.11.2]
        at com.azure.identity.implementation.IdentityClient.lambda$getManagedIdentityConfidentialClientApplication$5(IdentityClient.java:141) ~[azure-identity-1.11.2.jar:1.11.2]
        at reactor.core.publisher.MonoDefer.subscribe(MonoDefer.java:45) ~[reactor-core-3.6.3.jar:3.6.3]
...

I have tried setting the credentials as environment variables with the same exception being thrown.
I expect a successful connection to the ASB queue and consumption of messages.

The NoSuchMethodError indicates that the method doesn't exist in the target library.
Usually, this is due to incompatibility between library versions, specifically with the Azure Identity SDK (azure-identity) and the MSAL.
Ensure that you are using compatible versions of azure-identity, spring-cloud-azure-servicebus-starter and other related libraries.

I am using the most current versions of all libraries so I would not expect this error.

It seems like the implementation of the logPii(boolean) method was moved to AbstractApplicationBase.Builder (from AbstractClientApplicationBase.Builder)
with version 1.15.0 of com.microsoft.azure:msal4j. Maybe it will work with version 1.14.3?
